# "mcar: contract violation" new to Scheme need some answers :)

Tags: graph, scheme

I am new to Scheme and I have some questions.

First I want to make a graph and after that to use it for some stuff (like Dijkstra and etc.) First I wanted to make a function that returns what is the count of the Vertexes (not sure if that is a word). But I get this error and I just can't realise what is it and why I am getting it.

Also when I get the number of the vertexes I want to make a list with pairs every pair will give me information for a given vertex but I don't know how to do it.

(example if there are 4 vertexes the list should be ((0,-1) (0 -1) (0 -1) (0 -1)) "-1" will be like infinity since there will be no "weights" under 0 )

I am sure there are 1182498 better ways to do the algorithm but I would like to try with my idea. But still I don't have enough experience with Scheme.

Here is my code with the error:

```
(define G '((A (B 6) (E 5)) 
        (B (D 3)) 
        (C (A 1) (D 1))
        (D (C 7) (E 5) (W 3)) 
        (E (D 4) (F 10)) 
        (F)
        ))
(define (getNumV G)
(if (null? (car G)) 0)
(+ 1 (getNumV (cdr G))))
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! Really good answer I didn't know that lenght is available. Can I use it for getting the number of the inside lists too? (I am sorry for my English I mean if I want to know for the example the size of (car G) would it be right?)

Comment: @uselpa thank you again. Can you help me with my second problem with the list (0 -1) (0 -1)... I am really sorry I know probably it is something very easy but if I make the list ((0 -1) (0 -1)) and now I want to change the second "-1" Should I do something like (+ 1 (cdr(cdr list))) or I have to do something different ?

Comment: Please make this a separate question, so that you have space to describe exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `car` if the list is empty, so the test is simply `(null? G)`, not `(null? (car G))`.

Also, you have a closing parenthesis after the `0` which is wrong, both with regards to logic and because in Scheme an `if` is required to have an *else* part (you can use `when` or `unless` to avoid this).

So the code should be

```
(define (getNumV G)
  (if (null? G)
      0
      (+ 1 (getNumV (cdr G)))))
```

so that

```
(display (getNumV G))
=> 6
```

Also, try to indent your code properly, and to have no dangling closing parentheses.

It would be cleaner to use a generic name for the list parameter of your procedure such as `lst`, not the name of the real list `G`:

```
(define (getNumV lst)
  (if (null? lst)
      0
      (+ 1 (getNumV (cdr lst)))))

(display (getNumV G))
=> 6
```

Note that you can use the build-in procedure `length` instead of your `getNumV`:

```
(display (length G))
=> 6
```

Comment: Instead of just use `lenght` one could keep the name  `(define getNumV lenght)`